# Angular2: Service injection into AuthGuard breaks injection into other services

Tags: angular, service, dependency-injection

Starting a new project, I took some of my services with me.

- TokenService uses UserService to check tokens,
- UserService posts and stores the current User,
- AuthService uses TokenService and UserService to provide http headers
- Api uses AuthService to get http headers

These services worked well in my last project and don't seem to have any circular dependencies.

In my new project, I needed an AuthGuard which also gets the UserService injected. As soon as I add the UserService to the AuthGuard's constructor, Angular fails to resolve UserService as a dependency in my other services.
Everything works fine without the injection into AuthGuard.

Since this seems to happen not only for UserService but also for example for AuthService, I was guessing that my problems don't arise from the services but from the way they are provided.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { App } from './app.component';
import { AppState, InternalStateType } from './app.service';
import { GlobalState } from './global.state';
import { NgaModule } from './theme/nga.module';
import { PagesModule } from './pages/pages.module';
import {UserService} from "./services/user.service";
import {DefaultGuard} from "./pages/default.guard";
import {AuthService} from "./services/auth.service";
import {TokenService} from "./services/token.service";
import {Api} from "./services/api.service";

// Application wide providers
const APP_PROVIDERS = [
  AppState,
  GlobalState,
  UserService,
  DefaultGuard,
  AuthService,
  TokenService,
  Api
];

@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [App],
  declarations: [
    App,
  ],
  entryComponents: [
  ],
  imports: [ // import Angular's modules
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgaModule.forRoot(),
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    PagesModule,
    routing
  ],
  providers: [ // expose our Services and Providers into Angular's dependency injection
    APP_PROVIDERS
  ]
})

export class AppModule {

  constructor(public appState: AppState) {
  }
}
```

**pages.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }  from '@angular/common';
import { routing }       from './pages.routing';
import { NgaModule } from '../theme/nga.module';
import { AppTranslationModule } from '../app.translation.module';
import { Pages } from './pages.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, AppTranslationModule, NgaModule, routing],
  declarations: [Pages],
})
export class PagesModule {
}
```

The AuthGuard
**default.guard.ts** is used in the router belonging to pages.module.ts

```
import {Injectable, Inject} from "@angular/core";
import {CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot} from "@angular/router";
import {UserService} from "../services/user.service";

@Injectable()
export class DefaultGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    public userService: UserService
  ) {}

  public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (!this.userService.isAdminUser()) {
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Dependecies of my services:

**user.service.ts**

```
constructor(
    private http: Http,
  ) {
  }
```

**api.service.ts**

```
constructor(
    private http: Http,
    private auth: AuthService,
  ) {
  }
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
constructor(
    public userService: UserService,
    private tokenService: TokenService,
    private http: Http,
  ) {}
```

**token.service.ts**

```
constructor(
    public userService: UserService
  ) {
  }
```

So to recap: Everything works until I inject UserService into DefaultGuard.
Injecting UserService into DefaultGuard causes a dependency resolve error in TokenService.
Injecting AuthService into DefaultGuard causes a dependency resolve error in  ApiService and so on.

Any ideas on whats wrong here?

**Update**
So it seems like the order in which services are imported and/or injected plays a role in this issue. Although I am not sure how exactly.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution for my particular problem:

The whole DI mess was caused by the injection of `Http` into `UserService`. So I split up `UserService` into `CurrentUserService` which only takes care about storing the current user (Thats what's needed by `AuthService` etc) and `UserService` which uses `Http` to post and get users from the BE.

This is clearly a better, more separated organization of my services although I still don't understand what exactly caused the problem (It worked in my last project after all).

It may be worth mentioning that I am using the [ng2-admin template](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin) to build the app. Maybe there were other dependencies somewhere in the background.